# Excluding a Column with Filter views in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to using Google sheets so please bear with me.

I am making a waitlist for clients.  I have filter view working to filter, the date of first contact and availability by day and time.  I'm trying to figure out how to keep column A static so that it is just a list of numbers 1,2,3, etc

I have the range of the filter starting at c2 to exclude columns a and b but when I apply the filter the numbers move with the clients information instead of staying static. I'm sure there is a better way to do this with formulas but I'm trying to be make a sheet where I am able to easily view the information by their schedule availability. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rAw8kYibGWX9_rSIF6ZKvWmQoNUGtT7ifRW-VXBISw4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: We will need a little more information about what you are trying to do. An example sheet would be helpful. What are you trying to filter for? Is the schedule of availability the clients' availability? And what is the purpose of the static column of numbers?

Comment: Im not sure how to post an image.  Yes it's my clients availability.   The static number is just so I can tell them, "for a Thursday appointment you are "#" in line."  Kind of stupid, but I know generally how long each client takes to finish, so knowing that they are number 6 in line they can expect to wait about 6 months.  Each client is on a row and each day is on a column.  Im using filter views with a condition if there is text or no text in the days row.  appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: It would definitely be easier to help you if you could share a sample sheet, as explained here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en.   Even just your column headers and a few typical rows of data, with no sensitive values (eg. dummy names) would make things clearer.  And clarify which columns you want filtered and how.  But as you say, the filter view should not normally be sorting the columns you've excluded.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I edited the first post to include a link.

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? Create a different filter view for each day while keeping the column A static?

Comment: I want to filter by ascending date, and one day per filter view.  For example have a filter view for Thursday that sorts the date, and excludes rows that have a blank spot in the thursday column.

Comment: And do you exclusively want to use filter views or are you also opened to a solution using [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)?

Answer (score 1):

I deleted my earlier answer, which hadn't understood your filtering issue properly.  But as an alternative to @JLMosher's answer using a script, I believe that this formula based solution also anwers your question.  The formula is as follows:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,1,
   IF(SUBTOTAL(109,INDIRECT("A"&ROW()))>0,
     MAX(INDIRECT("B2:B"&ROW()-1))+1,0))
```

It basically looks at any column that contains just numeric values.  Then it takes the subtotal value just for that row.  Since hidden rows have a subtotal of zero (if using subtotal code 109), any row that returns a subtotal of zero, we do not increment our sequential number count.  Each unhidden row adds 1 to the highest count (max) from the rows above.  (I tried just adding 1 to the value from the row above, but if that is a hidden row, it's value will be 0, so that didn't work)

I've added a tab, Help-GK, to your sample sheet.
(**EDIT:**  Since the OP's sample sheet has been deleted, [here is my sample sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19QIUnimELCDeOeu-ZDL5d3nqWtLqG68tdDWGO5oO1z8/edit?usp=sharing))

Basically, the values in column B update to always show a sequential rank of numbers.  These numbers ignore any hidden rows.  In my sample, I've grouped rows 4:6, and rows 13:16, and then "hidden" these groups, by clicking on the [-] sign in the very far left.  To make them visible again, click on the [+].  Note the position in queue numbers change as you do this.

Note that these values also ignore any sorting - which may or may not be a bad thing.  If you sort, using the data filter dropdown arrows in each column header,  by Name (column C) or Date (column D) the rows will change order, but the position in queue numbers stay in the same relative position.

I haven't been able to create this as an array formula, so you need to copy down the formula in B2.

Lastly, I use your column A as the column to do a subtotal check on, but it could be any column with all numeric values, including a date column, I believe.

Let me know if this is useful to you, or if I've misunderstood again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you are trying to do with filters. Any filter that filters out rows will not ignore columns even if they are outside your filter range. You can sort without an issue but not filter out rows (like when you filter out blanks on the days of the week).

I wrote a script that will do what I believe you are wanting to do. Here is a link to an altered example sheet (you will have to make a copy of it to edit):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Ryqcdr0KGyUT1X1Ty2TD4I3q1y2XiXubZVwz2rV8Ec/edit?usp=sharing

I added a row at the top for check boxes.
And wrote the following code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

function onEdit(e) {
  
  var range = e.range;
  var value = e.value;
  var column = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  
  var dataArray = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  sheet.showRows(1,sheet.getMaxRows());
  
  if(row == 1 && value == 'TRUE') {
    sheet.getRange('C3:J').sort(column);
    var n = 1;
    for(var i = 2; i < sheet.getMaxRows(); i++){ 
      if(dataArray[i][column] == '') sheet.hideRows(i+1, 1); 
      else {
        sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(n);
        n+=1;
      }
    }
  }
  else if(row == 1 && value == 'FALSE'){
    var n = 1;
    for(var i = 2; i < sheet.getMaxRows(); i++){
      sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(n);
      n+=1;
    }
  }
}
```

You can add a row to the top of your sheet like in my example sheet, add the checkboxes and then paste this code in the script editor (Tools > Script Editor). You will have to name the script and then give the code permission to run.

The script will look at the cell when you click on a check box, sort the sheet by that column, hide all rows with blanks in that column, re-number your column A. When you unclick a check box, it will unhide all rows and re-number column A.

Also, you can just make a copy and use the sheet linked to above if that works for you.

Comment: I forgot to part of the code that hides the rows the first time around. I edited it. The above code should also hide rows with blanks in them.

Comment: I edited the code again to unhide rows and renumber column A when a checkbox is un-checked.

Comment: Where do you learn to write scripts like that for sheets?

Comment: You can learn a lot here on stack overflow. Also this is JavaScript so why tutorials on that. https://www.w3schools.com/ is a good place to start. When Googleing for answers include key words like Google sheets app scripts JavaScript etc. YouTube has done tutorials.

Comment: If this solution worked for you please upvote and accept this as a solution so others can find it. Good luck!